# Quartz scheduler job not triggering in spring 5.2.3 version, any suggestions?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler

I have tried trigger Quartz scheduler(2.2.1)
with latest version 5.2.3 but its not working. Then I have downgrade version then it's working. Can you please help me out to fix this

Comment: Could you please describe what exactly is not working? "Not working" can mean lots of things - you cannot compile your code, or you get some runtime exceptions when your application starts, or when Quartz starts or when Quartz attempts to execute a job etc. We run all Quartz versions between 1.8.6 and 2.3.2 with Spring 5.2.4 and observe no issues whatsoever.

Comment: Job(Quartz attempts to execute a job) not triggering when we use the Quartz scheduler(2.2.1) with latest version 5.2.3.If possible share me example so that i can use it

Comment: You can download and try our test webapps that use various Quartz versions from GitHub: https://github.com/quartzdesk/quartzdesk-test-webapps. If you want a test webapp that uses Quartz 2.2.1 and Spring 5.2.3, then you should look at quartzdesk-test-quartz-v2-2-x/quartzdesk-test-quartz-v2-2-1.